# Run multiple db queries in parallel

Tags: mysql, node.js

This script below is for testing an option to clone a database at better speed.

It uses nodes js to run multiple db queries in parallel. So far the result is the same. It seems like multiple connections to the server was opened at once, but the queries are still executed in sequence.

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
async = require('async');

// get list of tables
//
var uuid = 'def';
var default_db = 'abc';

var makeConnection = function () {
    return mysql.createConnection({
                host: 'localhost',
                user: 'root',
                password: 'password',
                multipleStatements: true
            });
}   

makeConnection().query('SHOW TABLES from ' + uuid, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var parallel = 5;
    var parallels = [], tables = [];
    var tables_count_from_zero = rows.length - 1;
    var tables_per_parallel = Math.ceil(rows.length / parallel);

    var makeQuery = function makeQuery (tables) { // factory function to create the queries
        return function doQuery (callback) {

            console.log('start');
            makeConnection().query('SET foreign_key_checks = 0;' + tables.join(''), function(err, rows, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('done');
                    callback(err, null);
                });
        };
    };

    var counter = 0;    
    for (row in rows) {
        counter++;

        var table_name = rows[row]['Tables_in_nilead'];

        tables.push('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + uuid + '.' + table_name + ' LIKE ' + default_db + '.' + table_name + ';');
        tables.push('INSERT ' + uuid + '.' + table_name + ' SELECT * FROM ' + default_db + '.' + table_name + ';');


        if (counter >= tables_per_parallel || row >= tables_count_from_zero) {
            counter = 0;            

            parallels.push(makeQuery(tables));

            tables = [];

            console.log('pushed ok');
        }
    }

    var initTimer = Date.now();

    async.parallel(parallels,

        // optional callback

        function(err, results) {
            console.log('Done ' + results + ' at: ' + (Date.now() - initTimer));
            // the results array will equal ['one','two'] even though
            // the second function had a shorter timeout.
        }
    );
});
```

// Edited: more tests:
Turning --innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit to either 0 or 2 speed it up at least 3 times

// Edited to add console log result as requested

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.acl_classes LIKE
>   mydb.acl_classes;INSERT def.acl_classes SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.acl_classes;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.acl_entries LIKE
>   mydb.acl_entries;INSERT def.acl_entries SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.acl_entries;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.acl_object_identities
>   LIKE mydb.acl_object_identities;INSERT def.acl_object_identities
>   SELECT * FROM mydb.acl_object_identities;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.acl_object_identity_ancestors LIKE
>   mydb.acl_object_identity_ancestors;INSERT
>   def.acl_object_identity_ancestors SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.acl_object_identity_ancestors;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.acl_security_identities LIKE mydb.acl_security_identities;INSERT
>   def.acl_security_identities SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.acl_security_identities;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.association LIKE mydb.association;INSERT def.association SELECT *
>   FROM mydb.association;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.association_type
>   LIKE mydb.association_type;INSERT def.association_type SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.association_type;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.cart LIKE
>   mydb.cart;INSERT def.cart SELECT * FROM mydb.cart;CREATE TABLE IF NOT
>   EXISTS def.cart_item LIKE mydb.cart_item;INSERT def.cart_item SELECT *
>   FROM mydb.cart_item;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.configuration LIKE
>   mydb.configuration;INSERT def.configuration SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.configuration;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.contact_mechanism
>   LIKE mydb.contact_mechanism;INSERT def.contact_mechanism SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.contact_mechanism;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.contact_mechanism_link LIKE mydb.contact_mechanism_link;INSERT
>   def.contact_mechanism_link SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.contact_mechanism_link;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.contact_mechanism_purpose_type LIKE
>   mydb.contact_mechanism_purpose_type;INSERT
>   def.contact_mechanism_purpose_type SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.contact_mechanism_purpose_type;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.contact_mechanism_type LIKE mydb.contact_mechanism_type;INSERT
>   def.contact_mechanism_type SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.contact_mechanism_type;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.container
>   LIKE mydb.container;INSERT def.container SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.container;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.container_type LIKE
>   mydb.container_type;INSERT def.container_type SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.container_type;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.credit_card LIKE
>   mydb.credit_card;INSERT def.credit_card SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.credit_card;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.currency LIKE
>   mydb.currency;INSERT def.currency SELECT * FROM mydb.currency;
>
> start
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.discount_price_component LIKE
>   mydb.discount_price_component;INSERT def.discount_price_component
>   SELECT * FROM mydb.discount_price_component;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.domain LIKE mydb.domain;INSERT def.domain SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.domain;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.facility LIKE
>   mydb.facility;INSERT def.facility SELECT * FROM mydb.facility;CREATE
>   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.geo_boundary LIKE mydb.geo_boundary;INSERT
>   def.geo_boundary SELECT * FROM mydb.geo_boundary;CREATE TABLE IF NOT
>   EXISTS def.geo_boundary_association LIKE
>   mydb.geo_boundary_association;INSERT def.geo_boundary_association
>   SELECT * FROM mydb.geo_boundary_association;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.group LIKE mydb.group;INSERT def.group SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.group;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.guide LIKE mydb.guide;INSERT
>   def.guide SELECT * FROM mydb.guide;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.guide_item LIKE mydb.guide_item;INSERT def.guide_item SELECT *
>   FROM mydb.guide_item;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.image LIKE
>   mydb.image;INSERT def.image SELECT * FROM mydb.image;CREATE TABLE IF
>   NOT EXISTS def.inventory_item LIKE mydb.inventory_item;INSERT
>   def.inventory_item SELECT * FROM mydb.inventory_item;CREATE TABLE IF
>   NOT EXISTS def.inventory_item_adjustment LIKE
>   mydb.inventory_item_adjustment;INSERT def.inventory_item_adjustment
>   SELECT * FROM mydb.inventory_item_adjustment;CREATE TABLE IF NOT
>   EXISTS def.inventory_item_variance LIKE
>   mydb.inventory_item_variance;INSERT def.inventory_item_variance SELECT
>   * FROM mydb.inventory_item_variance;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.inventory_item_variance_reason LIKE
>   mydb.inventory_item_variance_reason;INSERT
>   def.inventory_item_variance_reason SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.inventory_item_variance_reason;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.invoice LIKE mydb.invoice;INSERT def.invoice SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.invoice;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.invoice_address LIKE
>   mydb.invoice_address;INSERT def.invoice_address SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.invoice_address;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.invoice_item LIKE
>   mydb.invoice_item;INSERT def.invoice_item SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.invoice_item;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.language LIKE
>   mydb.language;INSERT def.language SELECT * FROM mydb.language;CREATE
>   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.message LIKE mydb.message;INSERT def.message
>   SELECT * FROM mydb.message;
>
> start
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.message_template LIKE mydb.message_template;INSERT
>   def.message_template SELECT * FROM mydb.message_template;CREATE TABLE
>   IF NOT EXISTS def.navigation LIKE mydb.navigation;INSERT
>   def.navigation SELECT * FROM mydb.navigation;CREATE TABLE IF NOT
>   EXISTS def.option LIKE mydb.option;INSERT def.option SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.option;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.option_value LIKE
>   mydb.option_value;INSERT def.option_value SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.option_value;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.order LIKE
>   mydb.order;INSERT def.order SELECT * FROM mydb.order;CREATE TABLE IF
>   NOT EXISTS def.order_address LIKE mydb.order_address;INSERT
>   def.order_address SELECT * FROM mydb.order_address;CREATE TABLE IF NOT
>   EXISTS def.order_adjustment LIKE mydb.order_adjustment;INSERT
>   def.order_adjustment SELECT * FROM mydb.order_adjustment;CREATE TABLE
>   IF NOT EXISTS def.order_item LIKE mydb.order_item;INSERT
>   def.order_item SELECT * FROM mydb.order_item;CREATE TABLE IF NOT
>   EXISTS def.order_item_address LIKE mydb.order_item_address;INSERT
>   def.order_item_address SELECT * FROM mydb.order_item_address;CREATE
>   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.order_item_role LIKE
>   mydb.order_item_role;INSERT def.order_item_role SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.order_item_role;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.order_role LIKE
>   mydb.order_role;INSERT def.order_role SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.order_role;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.page LIKE
>   mydb.page;INSERT def.page SELECT * FROM mydb.page;CREATE TABLE IF NOT
>   EXISTS def.party LIKE mydb.party;INSERT def.party SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.party;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.party_contact_mechanism LIKE
>   mydb.party_contact_mechanism;INSERT def.party_contact_mechanism SELECT
>   * FROM mydb.party_contact_mechanism;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.party_contact_mechanism_purpose LIKE
>   mydb.party_contact_mechanism_purpose;INSERT
>   def.party_contact_mechanism_purpose SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.party_contact_mechanism_purpose;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.party_relationship LIKE mydb.party_relationship;INSERT
>   def.party_relationship SELECT * FROM mydb.party_relationship;CREATE
>   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.party_role LIKE mydb.party_role;INSERT
>   def.party_role SELECT * FROM mydb.party_role;CREATE TABLE IF NOT
>   EXISTS def.party_role_type LIKE mydb.party_role_type;INSERT
>   def.party_role_type SELECT * FROM mydb.party_role_type;
>
> start
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.payment LIKE mydb.payment;INSERT def.payment
>   SELECT * FROM mydb.payment;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.payment_log
>   LIKE mydb.payment_log;INSERT def.payment_log SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.payment_log;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.payment_method LIKE
>   mydb.payment_method;INSERT def.payment_method SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.payment_method;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.post LIKE
>   mydb.post;INSERT def.post SELECT * FROM mydb.post;CREATE TABLE IF NOT
>   EXISTS def.product LIKE mydb.product;INSERT def.product SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.product;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.product_image LIKE
>   mydb.product_image;INSERT def.product_image SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.product_image;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.product_option LIKE
>   mydb.product_option;INSERT def.product_option SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.product_option;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.product_property
>   LIKE mydb.product_property;INSERT def.product_property SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.product_property;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.product_taxon
>   LIKE mydb.product_taxon;INSERT def.product_taxon SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.product_taxon;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.property LIKE
>   mydb.property;INSERT def.property SELECT * FROM mydb.property;CREATE
>   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.seo LIKE mydb.seo;INSERT def.seo SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.seo;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.shipment LIKE
>   mydb.shipment;INSERT def.shipment SELECT * FROM mydb.shipment;CREATE
>   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.shipment_address LIKE
>   mydb.shipment_address;INSERT def.shipment_address SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.shipment_address;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.shipment_item
>   LIKE mydb.shipment_item;INSERT def.shipment_item SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.shipment_item;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.shipment_item_inventory_item LIKE
>   mydb.shipment_item_inventory_item;INSERT
>   def.shipment_item_inventory_item SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.shipment_item_inventory_item;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.shipping_category LIKE mydb.shipping_category;INSERT
>   def.shipping_category SELECT * FROM mydb.shipping_category;CREATE
>   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.shipping_method LIKE
>   mydb.shipping_method;INSERT def.shipping_method SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.shipping_method;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.shipping_method_rule LIKE mydb.shipping_method_rule;INSERT
>   def.shipping_method_rule SELECT * FROM mydb.shipping_method_rule;
>
> start
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.shipping_methods_categories LIKE
>   mydb.shipping_methods_categories;INSERT
>   def.shipping_methods_categories SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.shipping_methods_categories;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.shipping_methods_zones LIKE mydb.shipping_methods_zones;INSERT
>   def.shipping_methods_zones SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.shipping_methods_zones;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.store_setting LIKE mydb.store_setting;INSERT def.store_setting
>   SELECT * FROM mydb.store_setting;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.tax_category LIKE mydb.tax_category;INSERT def.tax_category SELECT
>   * FROM mydb.tax_category;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.tax_rate LIKE mydb.tax_rate;INSERT def.tax_rate SELECT * FROM mydb.tax_rate;CREATE
>   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.taxon LIKE mydb.taxon;INSERT def.taxon SELECT
>   * FROM mydb.taxon;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.theme LIKE mydb.theme;INSERT def.theme SELECT * FROM mydb.theme;CREATE TABLE IF
>   NOT EXISTS def.unit_of_measurement LIKE
>   mydb.unit_of_measurement;INSERT def.unit_of_measurement SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.unit_of_measurement;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.unit_of_measurement_conversion LIKE
>   mydb.unit_of_measurement_conversion;INSERT
>   def.unit_of_measurement_conversion SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.unit_of_measurement_conversion;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   def.user LIKE mydb.user;INSERT def.user SELECT * FROM mydb.user;CREATE
>   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.user_group LIKE mydb.user_group;INSERT
>   def.user_group SELECT * FROM mydb.user_group;CREATE TABLE IF NOT
>   EXISTS def.variant LIKE mydb.variant;INSERT def.variant SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.variant;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.variant_image LIKE
>   mydb.variant_image;INSERT def.variant_image SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.variant_image;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.variant_option_value
>   LIKE mydb.variant_option_value;INSERT def.variant_option_value SELECT
>   * FROM mydb.variant_option_value;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS def.variant_price_component LIKE mydb.variant_price_component;INSERT
>   def.variant_price_component SELECT * FROM
>   mydb.variant_price_component;

Comment: can you add `console.log(tables.join(''))` after `console.log('start'))`, and paste console output?

Comment: @LucioM.Tato sure, I edited to add for you.

Comment: It seems like the create table.... is taking the longest amount of time, took me 50+ secs for all those tables.

Comment: if you do `var parallel = 1;`, it also takes 50+ secs?

Comment: @LucioM.Tato yup that Lucio, it also takes the same amount of time

Comment: then some layer is queuing your queries. Maybe mysql reuses the same internal "connection/session" when the connection request comes from the same process+user+ip?. Try using a different user for each "parallel": user1, user2, user3...

Comment: @LucioM.Tato Yup a logical deduction, however I still cannot find out which part is causing this yet. I have just tried different user per parallel connection, still same result.